# Bloquear una ventana principal de Tkinter en Python y mantener al boton X funcionando

Tags: python, tkinter

perdón si no fui especifico con la pregunta, pero es que es un poco larga y es mi primera vez consultando temas de programacion.
Estuve creando un Toplevel en Python con el modulo Tkinter y quería bloquear los eventos en la ventana principal mientras este está abierto. Googleando encontré el método "grab_set", que me lleva al otro extremo. Es decir, bloquea los eventos de la barra superior de la ventana (cerrar, maximizar y minimizar). ¿Existe algo similar a grab_set pero sin que esto ocurra?

Como alternativa, puedo bloquear todos los entrys y botones, pero no conozco ninguna forma de desvincular ni re-vincular los binds. ¿Existe alguna forma?

```
original = Tk()
entrada = Entry(original)
entrada.pack()

def otra_ventana(Self):
    ventana = Toplevel(original)
    ventana.grab_set()

original.bind("<F1>", otra_ventana)
```

Lo anterior es un código de prueba que tiene el problema que menciono.

Posdata: El problema solo ocurre cuando el Toplevel está abierto y se intenta cerrar la ventana principal.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Dante, ¿que sistema operativo usas? ¿Si es *nix qué entorno de escritorio usas? Lo digo porque la barra superior no es una parte  de la interfaz de tkinter propiamente dicha, es manejada directamente por el gestor de ventanas de turno (como kwin en KDE). En mi caso con entorno KDE Plasma la barra superior no queda bloqueada en ningún caso con `grab_set`... ¿Has personalizado alguno de los eventos de dichos botones de la barra?

Comment: Hola FJSevilla, uso Windows 10. Sobre la personalización de eventos, te soy sincero, no se del todo que significa, supongo que en este caso te referís al comando Protocol. Lo intenté usar, pero no sirvió, supongo que por el bloqueo de eventos de mouse y teclado de grab_set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pregunté en la versión en inglés y encontré una solución. Aquí les dejo el link para el que lo necesite.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60413086/lock-a-main-tkinter-window-in-python-and-keep-the-x-button-running/60416397?noredirect=1#comment106881018_60416397